# Oracle wm_concat to get one row then Case to check value

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I just want to sort by Painter or not Painter.

Oracle 10g

## Example Data:

**job_type**

- cook
- painter
- programmer
- mailman
- receptionist
- homemaker
- father
- mother
- etc

A person can have one line for each job type but they can have several jobs.

```
SELECT   ...(LIST OF FIELDS)...,
         WM_CONCAT(job_type) AS myJob_Type
FROM     (MYTABLE)
GROUP BY ...(LIST OF FIELDS)...
```

This gives me all of the job_type's in myJob_Type in a comma delimited list.
This works.

Now I want a way that I can sort by myJob_Type when the job has 'Painter' in it. I don't care about any other job type. So my thought was to make a case where if Painter is in the myJob_Type but when I do get it to work I get muiltple lines again.

```
SELECT ...(LIST OF FIELDS)...,
WM_CONCAT(job_type) AS myJob_Type,
CASE WHEN(job_ype like '%Painter%') THEN '1'
ELSE '0'
END

FROM     (MYTABLE)
GROUP BY ...(LIST OF FIELDS)...,
         job_ype
```

Another option tried.

```
SELECT ...(LIST OF FIELDS)...,
WM_CONCAT(job_type) AS myJob_Type,

CASE WHEN(myJobType like '%Painter%') THEN '1'
ELSE '0'
END

FROM      (MYTABLE)
GROUP BY  ...(LIST OF FIELDS)...,
          myJobType
```

Any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
select   ...
         wm_concat(job_type) as myJob_Type,
         sum(decode(job_type,'Painter',1,0))
from     ...
group by ...
```

Comment: Note that if you want to keep your `case` statement, you can just wrap it up in a `sum` function and it'll have the same effect.

Comment: Awesome... it worked without using the case statement and that is all I needed.  Thanks for the quick fix.